# Elm: How to create a view that doesn't return Msg?

Tags: elm

Currently, I have a nested component that only shows an error text. The view method receives a `Model` and returns `Html`, but the compiler complains saying that Html needs another value, so I ended up doing this:

```
view: Model -> Html ()
view error =
    div [class "docs-section error-bar"] [
      errorText error
    ]

errorText: Model -> Html ()
errorText error =
  case error.text of
    Nothing -> span [][]
    Just value -> text value
```

What I don't like is that I have to add the `()` value to the signature. Is there a way I can get rid of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Html` type](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html#Html) requires exactly one parameter, so you always have to give is *something*. Using `()` as a type parameter is a common way to put a dummy value there.

You could always define a type alias to avoid typing `()` every time:

```elm
type alias OnlyHtml = Html ()
```

Then you could change your type signatures appropriately:

```elm
view: Model -> OnlyHtml
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the alias name. =)

Answer (score 3):

Using `Html ()` will make it harder for you to compose this view with views that *do* send messages. Instead, use a type variable: `view: Model -> Html msg`.

The lowercase `m` is critically important: it means that this HTML can send any kind of message. Except that, sending a message of unknown type would break the type system, so instead it must not send any messages. If this seems strange, consider that `x : List a` means that the elements of `x` are of arbitrary type, and therefore there are no such elements: `x == []`.

Using the type variable is the most general type for your functions. All you're doing by using `()` instead is giving a more specific annotation, which is allowed. It's like claiming the empty list is actually a list of strings: sure, but all you've done is made that value unacceptable to a function that expects a list of another type. This is what I mean by `Html ()` is hard to compose without other views.

```
viewMsg : Html Msg
viewUnit : Html ()
viewTypeVariable : Html msg

views = [viewMsg, viewTypeVariable] -- This is okay
views = [viewMsg, viewUnit] -- This is a type error!
```