# What does a function with 2 values on the right side mean? (Model -> Html msg)

Tags: elm

I have encountered that in the guide:

```
viewValidation : Model -> Html msg
viewValidation model =
  let
    (color, message) =
      if model.password == model.passwordAgain then
        ("green", "OK")
      else
        ("red", "Passwords do not match!")
  in
    div [ style [("color", color)] ] [ text message ]
```

So this is a function, which takes the `Model`. 
`Html msg` usually looks to me like we are calling the function `Html` with the argument `msg`.

`msg` doesn't seem to play any role in any other part of the `viewValidation` function, though. So what does it mean and what is it for in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Html Msg` is just a type parameter, as `List Int` is. While `List Int` denotes a list that contains element of type `Int`, similarly `Html Msg` describes some HTML that can treat/emit messages of type `Msg`.

For example, if you have a button inside your HTML, it could look like this:

```
button [ onClick DoSomething ] [ text "caption" ]
```

Where `DoSomething` is a case of the `Msg` type.

Comment: Though, if I am not mistaken, `viewValidation` doesn't trigger any `msg`, right?

Comment: yes, you're right. As `List` needs to be defined with a parameter (you could use `List a`) even if it is empty, `Html` needs to be defined with a parameter even if that parameter is not used. If you want you could use `Html a`

Comment: Also if it doesn't return anything, you could use Html (). See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257407/elm-how-to-create-a-view-that-doesnt-return-msg-in-0-17

Comment: You don't want to use (). Instead, leave it as a type variable msg that can be instantiated to whatever type you need later. Unless you need an assurance that no message will be sent...

Comment: `Html msg` is misleading and confusing! If it's *any* use `Html a`.

Answer (score 8):

Don't mix the type definition with the normal execution of code. `Html` is not a function, it is a type that takes a parameter to define a type for a view function.

`Html msg` is the most general definition you can have as `msg` is a variable itself, so this returns Html that is independent of the msg type you are currently using. This could either be because it creates no event messages, or because the view function takes messages as parameters.

As the comments established `Html ()` would be a very narrow type that is constrained to return nothing.

The most common case though will be a view function returning `Html Msg` - i.e. Html with messages based on user interactions.

As Elm encourages componentization, you also need keep `Html.map` in mind. It's type signature is `Html.map : (a -> b) -> Html a -> Html b`. In the context of components this is more easily read as

```
Html.map : (Child.Msg -> Parent.Msg) -> Html Child.Msg -> Html Parent.Msg
```

Note that when you define your messages in your parent component, you will have something like:

```
type Msg = ChildMsg Child.Msg
```

which means that `ChildMsg` has type signature:

```
ChildMsg : Child.Msg -> Parent.Msg
```

So my view functions have a lot of

```
parentView model = 
  -- childView model.child |> Html.map ChildMsg
  Html.map ChildMsg (childView model.child)
```