# Confused about "Html msg"

Tags: elm

Consider this snippet:

```
type alias Model =
    { x : Int }


testFunc : Model -> Html String
testFunc model =
    div [] []
```

I am very confused here. `div` is a function that returns a `Html msg`. But  `testFunc` returns `Html String`.

How does this compile? Am i missing out on some very basic understanding here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363294/what-does-a-function-with-2-values-on-the-right-side-mean-model-html-msg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can *kind of* treat `msg` like [Generics in Object Oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java). This is not technically correct, though the concepts are similar. Just keep in mind that generic is not the correct terminology strictly speaking.

With that said, `div` is a function that returns a value of `Html` with a 'generic' type of `msg` (where `msg` could be any type). This would be written as `Html<A>` in Java or C#, where is `A` is a placeholder for any type.

Elm has [type inference](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/), so when the return type of `testFunc` is `Html String` Elm *infers* that `msg` must therefore be a `String` type.

Also note Elm requires the generic type be lower case (e.g `msg`). It's often confusing in Elm code as people will often define a real type of `Msg` and also name the generic placeholder type `msg`.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the technical difference between the generic types in elm and in OO programming? Is there a practical difference between *substituting* (OOP) and *infering* (Elm) the type? It's mentionned in the elm guide as a *type variable*, but at least from there, I could not see any difference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Someone else would probably do better than me in explaining the technical differences :) Conceptually though, I find they are very similar. Re type substituting vs type infering: OOP Substitution is concerned with sub types and class hierarchy. E.g if a method takes an `Animal` object as an argument, you can also use a `Dog` object (assuming the `Dog` class inherits from `Animal`). Whereas type infering is more about the compiler working out a type without the code explicitly setting it. E.g with `let a = "some text"`, Elm can deduce from the code that `a` must be of type `String`

Comment: Ok, makes sense. In practice I see so little difference that the two things merged in my mind. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind the difference between lower-case and upper-case type definitions. Lower-case `msg` in the signature of `div` is a generic type. It could have been named `a`, or anything else that starts with a lower-case.

In your definition of `testFunc`, you are simply using the `div` with a return type of `String`, which is not an issue for the elm compiler: this could very well be your `Msg` type.

In other words, the return type of `div` **is not** `Html Msg`, but is instead `Html msg`. This allows you to use it with whatever messages your component define, and makes it truly generic.

Comment: How can a `Html String` which is a concrete type accept `Html msg` which is a generic type?

Comment: That's the other way around. The generic type `Html msg` accept being returned as a `Html String`, because `msg` could really be anything.

For the list functions, for instance, they are usually defined as accepting `List a`, and not specifically `List String`. This way you can use them with `List Int`, etc... without having to redefine a new function.

Checkout [this reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/4jgv6x/beginner_question_on_the_elm_type_system_in_the/) on the topic, it might help you.